# wrong index in composite PRIMARY KEY in MyISAM

Tags: mysql, index, mariadb, myisam, mariadb-10.5

I use `MyISAM` for processing tables, as it is much faster to read large data from `MyISAM` as compared with `InnoDB` for `JOIN`s. I create map tables for bulk `INSERT`,

```
CREATE TABLE tag_map
(
article_id int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
tag_id mediumint(7) unsigned NOT NULL,
freq smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL,
INDEX(tag_id),
PRIMARY KEY(article_id,tag_id)
) ENGINE=MyISAM
```

I encountered a peculiar behavior and I am not sure if it is the expected behavior or a bug.

```
SELECT * FROM tag_map ORDER BY tag_id DESC LIMIT 10
```

does not order the results by `tag_map`.

In fact, the index is broken, but the table is not corrupt. I tried both `myisamchk` and `REPAIR TABLE`. I also `INSERT`ed the entire table into a newly created table, but exactly the same behavior.

Instead, if dropping the index

```
ALTER TABLE tag_map DROP INDEX tag_id
```

`ORDER BY` works as expected.

I confirm that the problem does not happen with `ARIA`.

Comment: How many table rows are there? Too short and it will just ignore the index as you are `select *`. Wrong results using an index looks buggy. A 3 byte `mediumint` isn't saving space or time over and `int`, does that have the same results?  I can't see an existing bug report and wouldn't mind seeing [a new bug report](https://jira.mariadb.org), especially as you seem to have a reproducible example.

Comment: @danblack it's about 700 million rows. I am experimenting to find the root of the problem, but it did not occur for smaller tables. I tried `int` too; different sorting result, but still wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Another diagnostic tool:

```
EXPLAIN SELECT ...
```

A likely repair:

```
ALTER TABLE tag_map DROP INDEX tag_id;
ALTER TABLE tag_map ADD INDEX(tag_id);
```

When you tried InnoDB, did you set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to about 70% of available RAM?

Comment: Re-creating the index had no effect; it is not a corrupted index. All my tables are InnoDB and have sufficiently large `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. It is not a matter of memory; when reading 200GB of data, the bottleneck is `I/O`. Reading MyISAM/ARIA files needs lower IOPS, and then, faster reading of the rows (though MariaDB will write it again on disk for JOIN via a temporary Aria table).